# How to fetch records by date property considering time zone?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate

Suppose I am in zone **UTC +0200** and I would like to save record with `date`: **2017-10-04**. I do it like this:

```
service!.date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: date.year, month: date.month, day: date.day))!
```

The date is saved like this:

```
2017-10-04 22:00:00 +0000
```

Now I need to display services for every day. Delegate ask me for a service for a `date`, example:

```
2017-10-04 22:00:00 +0000
```

Everything is fine, record is fetched and is ok.

But suppose I will travel to another country (**UTC +0100**), where delegate ask me for the same `date` but this time it looks like this:

```
2017-10-04 23:00:00 +0000
```

and... nothing is fetched. Why? Should not it be the same date? How to fix that?

The predicate how I fetch records looks like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "date = %@", date as NSDate)
```

Comment: You need save and fetch in the same format UTC I think

Comment: What do you mean? The app is in production... and everything is saved to persistent store. Now I need to fix that...

Comment: Always working with UTC must solve your issue, you need convert to UTC save it and fetch it after convert to UTC, I don´t know if I you understand me, sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, you only care about the date and not the time, but you're storing it using an `NSDate`, right? The problem is `NSDate` doesn't know about time zones. It's really just the number of seconds since some epoch, and the only way to convert it into a date is to know the time zone you're converting in.

The best answer here is probably to store it as a `String`, formatted like `2017-10-04`. Otherwise, as you've discovered, time zones cause the same day to be represented as different `Date`s.

If you're on iOS 10+, you can use `NSISO8601DateFormatter` to handle this, otherwise you can configure a `DateFormatter` with the appropriate format.

Alternatively, you could continue to store it as `NSDate`s, but take special care to always specify the UTC time zone when using `Calendar` to convert to/from date components.

---

If you need to fix an in-production app, the best solution here is probably to employ a heuristic that "rounds" each date, interpreted in UTC, to the nearest midnight value. That should effectively recover the timezone used to create the date. The only difficulty is in time zones that are 12 or more hours off from UTC (there is in fact a UTC+14:00 time zone), but I believe these time zones are mostly just uninhabited islands so you probably don't have any dates created from these time zones.

In any case, you'll need to go over all of your data, convert it to date components using UTC, then check the hour. Figure out if you need to round up or down to get to the nearest midnight, and adjust the actual date accordingly. Then you can take your corrected date components and write it back (either by just converting it back to an `NSDate` using UTC, or by converting it to a string, depending on whether you're modifying your data format or not).

Since this is CoreData, if you're going to switch to strings, you can implement a custom migration to handle this. Otherwise, you'll need some way to try and detect if you have affected data to begin with (as you don't want to be rewriting all your dates on every launch, just on the first launch after fixing this issue).

Comment: So is there a way to handle this somehow? The app is in the production... and need to workaround this.

Comment: The string solution is not considered... as it exists already as NSDate.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I've updated my answer with suggestions.

Comment: What is `NSISO8601DateFormatter ` for? Can I use it to resolve my problem?

Comment: It's just a specialized date formatter that handles ISO8601 dates, and I suggested it because it can produce the `2017-10-04` format very easily. If you're not going to switch your model to storing the date as a `String` then it's irrelevant. Just use the approach where you always use UTC when creating `NSDate` objects to use with your data.